# Blank page opening OpenEMM on Tomcat 8

Tags: tomcat, centos, centos6

Okay, so I'm still struggling to get OpenEMM running on my Centos6 server. When I run the /bin/openemm.sh start command it looks like Tomcat is working because I'm not getting an error and I have the Tomcat icon in my tab. However, all I'm getting is a blank page.

Suggestions? Here's the log:

******startup****************
    12-Oct-2013 15:21:20.848 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.init Loaded APR based Apache Tomcat Native library 1.1.28 using APR version 1.3.9.

```
12-Oct-2013 15:21:20.855 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.init APR capabilities: IPv6 [true], sendfile [true], accept filters [false], random [true].

12-Oct-2013 15:21:21.041 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.initializeSSL OpenSSL successfully initialized (OpenSSL 1.0.0-fips 29 Mar 2010)

12-Oct-2013 15:21:21.187 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-apr-8080"]

12-Oct-2013 15:21:21.201 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-apr-8009"]

12-Oct-2013 15:21:21.204 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load Initialization processed in 790 ms

12-Oct-2013 15:21:21.233 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal Starting service Catalina

12-Oct-2013 15:21:21.234 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.0.0-RC3

12-Oct-2013 15:21:21.243 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory /home/openemm-2013/webapps/openemm

12-Oct-2013 15:21:27.879 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory /home/openemm-2013/webapps/openemm-ws

12-Oct-2013 15:21:33.911 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory /home/openemm-2013/webapps/manual

12-Oct-2013 15:21:34.507 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scanJars At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.

12-Oct-2013 15:21:34.514 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-apr-8080"]

12-Oct-2013 15:21:34.519 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-apr-8009"]

12-Oct-2013 15:21:34.521 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start Server startup in 13315 ms
```

Comment: What URL are you requesting that returns a blank page?

Comment: www.[mywebsite].com:8080

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to access the ROOT web application but you do not have a ROOT web application deployed. From your logs, you only have /openemm, /openemm-ws and /manual

Looking at the latest OpenEMM download (2013-R2) it contains a sever.xml file that configures different context paths for some of those web applications. There are a couple of ways to deal with this. I recommend the following renames in your $CATALINA_BASE/webapps directory. Make sure you stop Tomcat before you do the renames.

- openemm -> ROOT
- openemm-ws -> openemm-ws2

Comment: Woo-hoo! That worked! Thanks so much for your help. I'll recheck, but I don't remember seeing that useful little tidbit in the OpenEMM docs.

Comment: Okay -- still have an issue. The index.html page opens, but the login link takes me to a 404 error. There is a logon.jsp file in the folder we have just renamed to ROOT. Not sure why the link isn't pointing to the file. Any ideas? I'll look through the install docs again as the day progresses.

Comment: I am advised by OpenEMM that I should be using Tomcat 6 rather than Tomcat 8. Could this difference cause errors to be thrown in processing the logon.jsp file?

Comment: Only if OpenEMM is using Tomcat internals directly rather than the Servlet API (always possible - JIRA had a similar issue with the Tomcat 6 to Tomcat 7 move). I suspect what is more likely that you are missing some configuration settings. You'll either have to dig through the installer to figure them out or you could try installing a default OpenEMM install and then look at what it configures.

Comment: Thanks, Mark -- I removed Tomcat 8 and installed Tomcat 6 and everything is working well now, so that apparently was the issue.